# Django admin actions logging: how to display initial and result value of field changes?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-logging

I want to add logging of admin changes in my django project. I've done some of that through LogEntry model:

```
from django.contrib.admin.models import LogEntry

class LogEntryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('__str__', 'action_time', 'user', 'content_type', 'object_id', 'object_repr', 'action_flag', 'change_message')
    list_filter = ('content_type',)
    search_fields = ['user__username',]
    date_hierarchy = 'action_time'

admin.site.register(LogEntry, LogEntryAdmin)
```

This is great, if I change some field of an object in my database, I can see log entry for that action. But in this log entry I can see only that "field was changed", and I also want to see initial and result value of this field. How can I achieve this functionality?

Comment: For me this question is still relevant, the answer from @conans does not provide an example of how this could be implemented. If there is a package that helps with that or example snipped, I'd also appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the LogEntry class and add custom fields and then use [pres_save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.pre_save), [post_save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.post_save) etc., to store the required entries to your custom model.